# Conditional Constraint Solving

Tags: constraint-programming

How would you approach the following constraint optimization problem:

- I have a set of integer variables `x[i]` that can takes only 4 values in the `[1,4]` range
- There are constraints of the form `C <= x[i]`, `x[i] <= C`, and `x[i] <= x[j]`
- There are also **conditional** constraints, but exclusively of the form "if `2 <= x[i]` then `3 <= x[j]`"
- I want to minimize the number of variables that have the value `3`

Edit: because I have a large (thousands) number of variables and constraints and performance is critical, I’m looking for a dedicated algorithm, not using a general-purpose constraint solver.

Comment: Which constraint modeling system do you use? For example, in MniZinc you can use `if ... then ... endif` construct.

Comment: I have thousands of variables and for this specialized problem, I was hoping to find a simple algorithm without a need for a full fledged solver. Without the conditional constraints, it’s very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a fairly simple and efficient algorithm for this particular problem.
It is enough to maintain and propagate intervals and start propagating the conditional constraints when the lower bounds become `>= 2`.
At the end, if the interval is exactly `[3,4]`, the optimal solution is to select `4`.

More precisely:

- initialize `l[i]:=1`, `u[i]:=4`
- propagate constraints until fixpoint as follows:

  - Constraint "`C<=x[i]`": `l[i]:=max(l[i],C)`
  - Constraint "`x[i]<=C`": `u[i]:=min(u[i],C)`
  - Constraint "`x[i]<=x[j]`": `l[j]:=max(l[j],l[i])` and `u[i]:=min(u[i],u[j])`
  - Constraint `2<=x[i] ==> 3<=x[j]`: if `2<=l[i]`, then `l[j]:=max(l[j], 3)`
- If `u[i]<l[i]`, there is no solution
- Otherwise, select:

  - `x[i]=l[i]` if `u[i]<=3`
  - `x[i]=u[i]` otherwise

This is correct and optimal because:

- any solution is such that `l[i]<=x[i]<=u[i]`, so if `u[i]<l[i]`, there is no solution
- otherwise, `x[i]=l[i]` is clearly a solution (but NOT `x[i]=u[i]` because it can be that `u[i]>=2` but `u[j]` is not `>=3`)
- bumping all `x[i]` from `3` to `4` when possible is still a solution because this change doesn't activate any new conditional constraints
- what remains are the variables that are forced to be `3` (`l[i]=u[i]=3`), so we have found a solution with the minimal number of `3`

In more details, here is a full proof:

- assume that a solution `x[i]` is such that `l[i]<=x[i]<=u[i]` and let's prove that this invariant is preserved by application of any propagation rule:

  - Constraint "`x[i]<=x[j]`": `x[i]<=x[j]<=u[j]` and so `x[i]` is both `<=u[i]` and `<=u[j]` and hence `<=min(u[i],u[j])`. Similarly, `l[i]<=x[i]<=x[j]` so `max(l[i],l[j])<=x[j]`
  - The constraints "`x[i]<=C`" and "`C<=x[i]`" are similar
  - For the constraint "`2<=x[i] ==> 3<=x[j]`": either `l[i]<2` and the propagation rule doesn't apply or `2<=l[i]` and then `2<=l[i]<=x[i]` implying `3<=x[j]`. So `3<=x[j]` and `l[j]<=x[j]` hence `max(3,l[j])<=x[j]`
- as a result, when the fixpoint is reached and no rule can be applied anymore, if any `i` is such that `u[i]<l[i]`, then there is no solution
- otherwise, let's prove that this `x[i]` is a solution where: `x[i]=l[i]` if `u[i]<=3` and `x[i]=u[i]` otherwise:

  - Note that `x[i]` is either `l[i]` or `u[i]`, so `l[i]<=x[i]<=u[i]`
  - For all constraints "`C<=x[i]`", at fixpoint, we have `l[i]=max(l[i],C)`, i.e., `C<=l[i]<=x[i]` and the constraint is satisfied
  - For all constraints "`x[i]<=C`", at fixpoint, we similarly have `u[i]<=C` and `x[i]<=u[i]<=C` and the constraint is satisfied
  - For all "`x[i]<=x[j]`", at fixpoint, we have: `u[i] = min(u[i],u[j])` so `u[i]<=u[j]` and `l[j] = max(l[j],l[i])`, so `l[i]<=l[j]`. Then:

    - If `u[j]<=3` then `u[i]<=u[j]<=3` so `x[i]=l[i]<=l[j]=x[j]`
    - Otherwise, `x[j]=u[j]` and `x[i]<=u[i]<=u[j]=x[j]`
  - For all "`2<=x[i] ==> 3<=x[j]`": assume `2<=x[i]`:

    - If `u[i]<=3`, then either:

      - `l[i]<=2` and the fixpoint means `l[j]:=max(l[j], 3)` so `3<=l[j]<=x[j]`
      - or `l[i]=3` and `3=l[i]<=l[j]<=x[j]`
    - If `u[i]>3`, then `3<u[i]<=u[j]` and `3<u[i]<=u[j]=x[j]`
- Finally the solution is optimal because:

  - if `l[i]=u[i]=3`, any solution must have `x[i]=3`
  - otherwise, `x[i] != 3`: if `u[i]<=3`, then either `u[i]=3` and `x[i]=l[i]<3` or `x[i]<=u[i]<3`; and if `u[i]>3` then `x[i]=u[i]!=3`

Comment: Should it be: Constraint `x[i]<=x[j]`: `l[j]:=max(l[j],u[i])` and `u[i]:=min(u[i],l[j])`

Comment: I am still wondering about optimality of the algorithm. In cases where several variables are blocking others to stay away from `3`, how do you decide which variables to move? Shouldn't there be some sort of backtracking with repeated constraint propagation?

Comment: The best way to be sure is to prove it... I've added a full proof and I think the algorithm is indeed correct and optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You could encode each variable as a pair of binary variables:

```
x[i] = 1 + 2*x2[i] + x1[i]
```

The inequality constraints can now be partly resolved:

```
1 <= x[i]   can be ignored, as always true for any variable
2 <= x[i]   implies (x2[i] or x1[i])
3 <= x[i]   implies x2[i]
4 <= x[i]   implies (x2[i] and x1[i])

1 >= x[i]   implies (!x2[i] and !x1[i])
2 >= x[i]   implies !x2[i]
3 >= x[i]   implies (!x2[i] or !x1[i])
4 >= x[i]   can be ignored, as always true for any variable

x[i] <= x[j] implies (!x2[i] or x2[j]) and 
                     (!x1[i] or x2[j] o x1[j]) and
                     (!x2[i] or !x1[i] or x1[j])
```

Conditional constraint

```
if 2 <= x[i] then 3 <= x[j]
```

translates to

```
x2[j] or !x1[i]
```

The encoding shown above can be directly written as Conjunctive Normal Form ([CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)) suitable for a [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver). Tools like [SATInterface](https://github.com/deiruch/SATInterface) or [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/index.html) help to automate this translation.

To minimize the number of variables which have value `3`, a counting circuit combined with a digital comparator could be constructed/modelled.

Variable `x[i]` has value `3`, if `(x2[i] and !x1[i])` is true. These expressions could be inputs of a counter. The counting result could then be compared to some value which is decreased until no more solutions can be found.

**Bottom line:**
The problem can be solved with a general purpose solver like a [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver) ([CaDiCal](https://github.com/arminbiere/cadical), [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), [Cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat)) or a constraint solver like [Minizinc](https://www.minizinc.org/). I am not aware of a dedicated algorithm which would outperform the general purpose solvers.